# How to compare enums?

Tags: vba, ms-access-2013

I'm having a lot of trouble checking if my enums are equal.

My enum is declared like this:

```
Public Enum POKEMON_VERSION
    RED_BLUE_YELLOW = 1
    GOLD_SILVER = 2
    ...
End Enum
```

My form is like this:

```
Const pokemonVersion As Variant = POKEMON_VERSION.GOLD_SILVER
Public Sub Search_ButtonClick()
    Dim sql As String
    sql = Get_Pokemon(pokemonVersion ) 'which is GOLD_SILVER
    Me.mySubform.Form.RecordSource = sql
    Me.mySubform.Requery
End Sub
```

Here's the method I'm having a problem with, my switch statement:

```
  Public Function Get_Pokemon( version As Variant ) As String
     Select Case version
          Case version = RED_BLUE_YELLOW
              ' don't get ability or nature, didn't exist in this version
               Get_Pokemon = "SELECT * FROM ..." 
          Case version = GOLD_SILVER
               Get_Pokemon = "SELECT * FROM ..."
     End Select
  End Function
```

But when I run the program, it finds that `version` is not matched in any of my cases (in this example, should match GOLD_SILVER). I think the problem may be that I'm comparing a `Variant` to an `Enum`'s "value".

How do I fix this?

I'd wouldn't mind changing the type of my `Const pokemonVersion`, but the Enum's "value" does need to be stored in a `Const` variable, and this was the best I could figure out.

Comment: I suspect `As Variant` to be the source of the difficulty.  That should probably be `As POKEMON_VERSION`

Comment: @RobertHarvey I'm new at VBA but when I try `Const pokemonVersion As POKEMON_VERSION = POKEMON_VERSION.GOLD_SILVER`, I get the error message `Compile error: Expected: type name`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem has nothing to do with the `Const` or the `Enum`.  It has to do with your `Select` syntax.  You are selecting based on `version`, so the cases need to be members of the enumeration.  When you do this (parentheses added for clarity)...

```
Case (version = RED_BLUE_YELLOW)
```

...it evaluates to this...

```
Case (version = 1)
```

...so if you pass it a `RED_BLUE_YELLOW` for `version`, you get...

```
Case (1 = 1)
```

...which is:

```
Case True
    '...
Case False
    '...
Case False
'etc.
```

You can either change the `Select` to switch on `True`...

```
Public Function Get_Pokemon(version As POKEMON_VERSION) As String
    Select Case True
        Case version = RED_BLUE_YELLOW
            ' don't get ability or nature, didn't exist in this version
             Get_Pokemon = "SELECT * FROM ..."
        Case version = GOLD_SILVER
             Get_Pokemon = "SELECT * FROM ..."
    End Select
End Function
```

...or use the much clearer and working syntax below:

```
Public Function Get_Pokemon(version As POKEMON_VERSION) As String
    Select Case version
        Case RED_BLUE_YELLOW
            ' don't get ability or nature, didn't exist in this version
             Get_Pokemon = "SELECT * FROM ..."
        Case GOLD_SILVER
             Get_Pokemon = "SELECT * FROM ..."
    End Select
End Function
```

Comment: Okay, so Case version=GOLD_SILVER always fails, even though version=2 and GOLD_SILVER=2, interestingly enough. I think it has to do with types. BUT Case GOLD_SILVER succeeds! Very, very interesting.

Comment: @rib.usa - That's because `version = [anything]` is `True`, but `version` is a number, not a boolean. It's like testing `If 2 = True Then '...`